# Where are some of the objects that get passed as arguments in protocol methods created?

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager

I'm a bit unclear on where some of the objects that are getting passed as arguments in some Objective C protocol methods are being created. Let's look for example at the code below which is one of the protocol methods for the CLLocationManagerDelegate which updates the location of an object:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"%@", newLocation);
    NSTimeInterval t = [[newLocation timestamp] timeIntervalSinceNow];

    if (t < -180) {
        return;
    }

    [self foundLocation:newLocation];

}
```

The question I have here is about newLocation. According to the Apple documentation, newLocation is provided to the method by a CLLocationManager object. But where is an object like this created? It all seems to happen in a blackbox somewhere and then gets automatically passed to the method...or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

A black box is exactly where that object is coming from. You don't know, and don't care. The inner workings of CLLocationManager are private, and therefore should be considered volatile and unknowable.

Generally speaking, no method should ever care where arguments are coming from, as long as they're handled correctly within the scope of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if by "blackbox" you mean "the Core Location framework," they yes, that's where it's created. The caller (Core Location in this case) will generally create this kind of object and pass it to you. In the general case, it shouldn't matter to you, though.